# Plot a regression equation with mean standard error in R

Tags: r, statsmodels

I would like to plot values from the image from a model regression, with R.

[https://imgur.com/DDbP29T](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioCLb.png)

my plan is to create the equation and plot with the curve function

```
eqn = function(x){ZZZ}
curve(eqn, from=0, to=50, n=50)
```

I expect a logarithmic growth curve

Comment: Please try to make your question reproducible. You included some code and methodology, but what else have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Something along these "lines" as it were; Consult `?curve`, `?plot` for further details about the arguments used, and your stats books for why I picked 1.96 as a multiplier for the sum (roughly) of the se values

```
 eqn = function(x){62.259+11.395*log(x) -10.268}
 curve(eqn, from=0, to=50, n=50, ylim=c(0,100))
 lines(x=seq(0,50),y=eqn(seq(0,50))+ 1.96*8.5, lty=3)
 lines(x=seq(0,50),y=eqn(seq(0,50))- 1.96*8.5, lty=3)
```

[image]

(I'm guessing you are trying to reproduce a plot you have seen constructed in the SAS product named "JMP". I used it for a while around 2008-2009, but found it too limited in its capabilities, not to mention becoming quite expensive.)